# javscript - remove string-code from js loaded from third party source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to capture the click event and it is working fine, but some links the JS is preventing for capturing the click event.

The code is like:

```
(function() {
  var layer = document.getElementById("Layer");
  if (layer) {
    var listen = function(obj, e, fn) {
      if (obj.addEventListener) { obj.addEventListener(e, fn, false); } else { obj.attachEvent("on"+e, fn); }
    };
    listen(layer, 'click', function (evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      try { evt.cancelBubble(); } catch (e) { /* ignore */ }
      window.open(window.clickTag, '_blank');
    });
  }
})();
```

so I can for example remove the code or override `stopPropagation`

```
evt.stopPropagation();
  try { evt.cancelBubble(); }
```

using my own JS code.
I have tried to get the access to the js code using:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
iframe.addEventListener('load', function(event){
    console.log("iframe Loaded", event);
});
```

and in the browser console I can see the log as:

```
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "load", target: iframe, currentTarget: iframe, eventPhase: 2, …}
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: Array(9)
0: iframe
1: a
2: div.banner2
3: div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.col-sm-12.col-xs-12
4: div.row
5: div.container
6: body
7: html
8: document
```

Update:
when I try like

```
iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('click', function (e)
```

I am getting error as below. so is there any way to listen event on Iframe window.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "mysite.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at HTMLIFrameElement
```

Comment: Manipulating a third-party site without their authorization is usually a security issue. These days most browsers forbid that.